# PySpark write parquet in parallele

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running a PySpark job using 6 workers, during this job all my transformations are being executed into multiple workers, however when I'm trying to save my output as parquet file, I can see from Spark UI that is using only 1 executor, which make it very slow compared to other transformations, I've tried different approach, changing repartitions, saving into memory using .persist() but nothing changed, here is my code :

```
self.data = self.data.repartition(6)
self.data.write.parquet(self.output_local_path + "/data", mode="overwrite", compression="snappy")
```

and as you can see from Spark UI :
[image]

[image]

Don't mind the execution time I was just trying to debug it using some small files, for my real data transformations are taking around 2-3 minutes, but writing into parquet can be around **20minutes**, which is really to much. (Around 70M rows x 60 cols)

Can you guys help me identify what I'm missing here? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the issue was not exactly from the .write function, during the process I was doing a skewed outer join, to fix the issue this is the code I used :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast 
spark_df.join(broadcast(df_rates),...)
```